# Java - Gamma algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, javafx

I am trying to code an algorithm to implement Gamma Correction but I am unable todo so with below code, because of a high power base. Wondering if anyone could fix below code to raise color values between 0,1   Thanks

Comment: Check this out: https://bostjan-cigan.com/java-gamma-correction-algorithm/

Comment: Thanks, I have seen but I want to use the .getRed , .getGreen , .getBlue functions

Comment: I believe the sigmoid function can be used to squish everything onto [0,1]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your math.

`int / int` will cause a truncation.

If `red = 9` and you execute `9 / 255` the result is `0`.

Try making all your literal values floating point
(for example `255.0` instead of `255`).